# Printing a two's complement binary string of an 8 bit byte in javascript

Tags: javascript, formatting, byte, string-formatting, twos-complement

Printing a two's complement binary string of an 8 bit byte in javascript.

<sub>Had to do this today, and didn't found an answer on the first pages so I'm sharing in case anyone may ever need.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```js
function printByteToBinary(n) {
    n = n < 0 ? n + 256 : n;
    return ("00000000" + n.toString(2)).slice(-8);
}
```